# Galois group action property

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I'm trying to prove the following proposition about the Galois group $Gal(L/K)$, for an algebraic extension of a field $K$:

*Let $a_1, \dotsc, a_n, a'_1, \dotsc, a'_n \in L$.
If $L = K(\alpha_1, \dotsc, \alpha_n)$, then there exists at most one $\tau \in Gal(L/K)$ such that $\tau(\alpha_i) = \alpha'_i$ for every $1 \leq i \leq n$.*

If I understand the statement correctly, what I need to prove is that, assuming that such a $\tau \in Gal(L/K)$ exists, if $\sigma \in Gal(L/K)$ satisfies
$$ \sigma(\alpha_i) = \alpha'_i \text{ for every } 1 \leq i \leq n,$$
then $\sigma = \tau$.
So i pick some $\sigma \in Gal(L/K)$ that satisfies the above identity and some $\beta \in L$, and I try to show that $\sigma(\beta) = \tau(\beta)$.
I guess that I should use in some way the fact that $L$ is generated by the elements $\alpha_1, \dotsc, \alpha_n$, but I don't see how to do that, since $\{\alpha_1, \dotsc, \alpha_n\}$ is not really a basis of $L$ as a vector space over $K$.

---

A consequence of this proposition is that if $\alpha_1, \dotsc, \alpha_r$ are the roots of a polynomial $f \in K[x]$, then $Gal(L/K)$ acts faithfully over $\{\alpha_1, \dotsc, \alpha_r\}$ (since for every $\sigma \in Gal(L/K)$, $\sigma$ maps a root of $f$ to a root of $f$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if $K(a_1,\dots,a_n)/K$ is algebraic, then every element of $K(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ can be expressed as a polynomial in $a_1,\dots a_n$ with coefficients in $K$. You can show this using induction over $n$, if you want.

But then since every $\tau\in\operatorname{Gal}(K(a_1,\dots,a_n)/K)$ is a $K$-homomorphism, it acts on every one of those polynomials by simply leaving the coefficients intact (since those are in $K$) and just mapping the "variables" $a_i$ to their images. So the image of any polynomial expression in $a_i$ is fully determined by the image of the $a_i$. And since every element of the field in question is such a polynomial, its image is also fully determined by the image of the $a_i$. Meaning that there is at most one possible $K$-homomorphism mapping $a_i$ to $a_i'$.

Now you just need to formalize these arguments.

Comment: Thank for the answer. I've seen that for a simple algebraic extension $K(\alpha)$ then $K(\alpha) = K[\alpha]$ holds. So your first sentence implies that I can generalize this to multiple generators to obtain $K(\alpha_1, \dotsc, \alpha_n) = K[\alpha_1, \dotsc, \alpha_n]$ by induction over $n$. Is this correct?

Comment: Also, I think that $\{\alpha^i \; | \; 0 \leq i < deg(m_{\alpha,K}) \}$ is a basis for $K(\alpha)$ (since it is isomorphic to $K[x] / (m_{\alpha,K})$. So I think that it should also imply that $\{\alpha_1^{m_1}, \dotsc, \alpha_n^{m_n} \; | \; 0 \leq m_i < deg(m_{\alpha_i,K}) \}$ is a basis for $K(\alpha_1, \dotsc, \alpha_n\}$. Is this conclusion also correct?

Comment: Yes, you can. Use that $K(a_1,\dots,a_k,a_{k+1})=K(a_1,\dots,a_k)(a_{k+1})=K[\dots][\dots]=K[\dots]$.

Comment: Your latter conclusion needs some more care, though. For instance, it's not true for $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2,-\sqrt2)$, since $\{1,\sqrt2,-\sqrt2\}$ is not linearly independent.

Comment: Oh, yes, I see. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Take care, though, I made a mistake: you don't even get a generating system. For instance, $\{1,\sqrt2,\sqrt3\}$ is not a basis of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$, because it doesn't generate $\sqrt6$.

Comment: I was about to write the same counterexample haha. Clearly we also need "mixed" terms when dealing with multivariate polynomials...